# PB Select TODAY() Into :var From DUMMY

Tags: sql-server, date, format, powerbuilder

When I get TODAY in SELECT in PB, it returns 1900/1/1

```
date var
Select TODAY() Into :var From DUMMY
```

But when I assign to variable TODAY(), it works as expected

```
date var
var = today()
```

I use MS SQL Server 2016 and PowerBuilder 12.5.

I've supposed that the problem is in different date formats, but I have changed date format at my Windows locale in the way, that PB TODAY() returns **2018-10-08** and MSSQL GetDate() returns **2018-10-08 18:25:23.207**
So date parts have the same formats.

The problem is not in DUMMY table since I have created MS SQL DUMMY table and inserted 1 row in it.

Also I'm wondering if there are any difference in **SELECT TODAY()** and **var = TODAY()**?
I suppose that 1st variant returns MS SQL server time but 2nd returns local time. Is not is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below SQL.

> `Select getdate() into :var From DUMMY;`

Answer (score 1):

You provided your own answer: Today() is a PowerScript function, GetDate() is the function on MS SQL. If you’re executing SQL, it needs to be a valid SQL statement for the server you’re executing against (except for the INTO :var part), and can’t include a PowerScript function.

Two other things:

1. “FROM DUMMY” is an Oracle thing, and I’m pretty sure it won’t work on MS. (You’re capturing your error codes after executing the SQL, right?)
2. I won’t say this is likely a critical problem, but as you point out, GetDate returns a datetime; I’d recommend that as your data type for the capture variable.

And yes, GetDate() will be your server’s date/time, Today() will be based on the local workstation.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for the description.

Comment: As for DUMMY table, I have created it's equivalent in MSSQL (**CREATE TABLE DUMMY (C1 INT) GO INSERT INTO DUMMY VALUES (1)**). So when I do **SELECT 123 INTO :somevar FROM DUMMY**, 123 value is set into somevar. The problem only with date. When I debug this part of code, I see that **TODAY** returns valid date, but **1900/1/1** is set into variable. So I'm confused. Is **SELECT TODAY() INTO ...** the same with **VAR = TODAY()** in PowerBuilder?